# How to get VS Code to suggest props and show types/descriptions?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I noticed that when I install third party React packages, prop suggestion works right out of the box:

[image]

Yet when I create my own components and put jsdoc style comments above each `PropType`, it doesn't work. Is there some way I can add these suggestions to my own components?